# ServiceNow renaming attachment not getting SysId

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

In ServiceNow, I have written script in business login - script actions.
While adding and deleting I am getting sysId but when renaming the attachment I am not able to get sys_id.

```
sendnotification();
function sendnotification()
{
    try
    {
        var r = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2('IqtrackTest', 'AttachmentPost');

        r.setStringParameterNoEscape('sys_id',current.sys_id);        
        r.setStringParameterNoEscape('sysparm_TableName',current.getTableName());
        r.setStringParameterNoEscape('Action',"Attachment_Renamed");

        var response = r.execute();
        var responseBody = response.getBody();
        var httpStatus = response.getStatusCode();
    }
    catch(ex) 
    {
        var message = ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `current` in this context? Also, this is a script action, so I'm guessing triggered by an event. It would help to know what the event is and what triggers it (e.g. eventQueue in an after update business rule).

Comment: What is the event when renaming the attachement? There is an event with attachment.rename in script action in that i have added the above code. Any other event i can plug with.

Comment: @Joey What is the event when renaming the attachement? There is an event with attachment.rename in script action in that i have added the above code. Any other event i can plug with

Comment: I see an event named `attachment.renamed`, is that what you mean? That gets triggered when an attachment file name is changed through the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  var record = new GlideRecord('sys_attachment');
  record.addQuery('user_name',gs.getUserName());
  record.orderByDesc('sys_updated_on');
  record.setLimit(1);
  record.query();
  if (record.next())
  {
    gs.print(record.getValue("sys_id"));
    gs.print(record.getDisplayValue("file_name"));
    gs.error("file name"+record.getDisplayValue("file_name"));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run this code in your Background Script

```
var temp= new GlideRecord('sys_attachment');
temp.addQuery('user_name',gs.getUserName());
temp.orderByDesc('sys_updated_on');
temp.setLimit(1);
temp.query();

if (temp.next()){
    gs.print(temp.getValue("sys_id"));
}
```